# Threading in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my application I have a parent thread. I want to know what will happen to the child thread if I suspend the execution of the parent thread? Will they continue their execution or will they will also get suspended and wait for the parent thread to resume its execution? Please help me.

Comment: You'd better show us some code.

Answer (score 4):

Threads don't really have a parent/child relationship - once a thread has been started, it's independent of the thread that created it.

(I'm concerned by your use of the word "suspend" for the parent thread though - suspending a thread is generally a bad idea. In particular, if you mean calling [`Thread.Suspend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx) you should be aware that that has been deprecated. What do you mean, exactly? If you're trying to coordinate work between threads, there are better ways.)

Sample code, showing four threads doing work, being paused, being resumed, and then the process terminating:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class A  
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Start off unpaused
        var sharedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            string prefix = "Thread " + i;
            Thread t = new Thread(() => DoFakeWork(prefix,
                                                   sharedEvent));
            // Let the process die when Main finished
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
        }
        // Let the workers work for a while
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Pausing");        
        sharedEvent.Reset();

        Thread.Sleep(3000);       
        Console.WriteLine("Resuming");
        sharedEvent.Set();

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Finishing");
    }

    static void DoFakeWork(string prefix, ManualResetEvent mre)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prefix + " working...");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            mre.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing a huge calculation in my application.My application has got a pause button.I want my application to pause if some1 clicks on the pause button,and resume its ececution if some1 clicks on Resume button.My application has a parent thread.And in two different function i have started 4 threads in each function.I am using threadpool.

Comment: @Sanchaita: You should pause *cooperatively* - e.g. within each worker thread, periodically check some shared Boolean value for whether you need to pause or not. Or you could just use a `ManualResetEvent`, and just wait for it periodically - Reset it on pause, and Set it on resume.

Comment: I am doing WaitOne to bring all my threads at 1 point.Where am i supposed to implement it.After the WaitOne or before it.And can i use suspend

Comment: @Sanchaita: Where are you supposed to implement what? I don't see why you still want to use Suspend when I've explained that it's deprecated and given you a complete example of how achieve pausing in a better way...

Comment: This pausing example is great. +1

Answer (score 2):

Threads don't really have the parent-child relationship in .Net - so suspending a thread will not suspend other threads that happen to have been created by it.

Answer (score 0):

in brief,if you mean child is the thread started from another thread that you call parent, than no the child threads don't get suspended just because the main thread was suspended.
check this example: 
http://www.codersource.net/microsoft-net/c-basics-tutorials/c-net-tutorial-multithreading.aspx